# model.fit() printing accuracy and loss afer evey batch_size

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I have model.fit() with verbose=1

but my output is printing for every batch size::

1920/323432 [..............................] - ETA: 19:21 - loss: 10.4622 - acc: 0.343 - ETA: 18:40 - loss: 10.5245 - acc: 0.339 - ETA: 18:32 - loss: 10.5452 - acc: 0.338 - ETA: 18:29 - loss: 10.5556 - acc: 0.337 - ETA: 18:30 - loss: 10.2380 - acc: 0.357 - ETA: 18:31 - loss: 10.3999 - acc: 0.347 - ETA: 18:37 - loss: 10.4978 - acc: 0.341 - ETA: 18:40 - loss: 10.5089 - acc: 0.340 - ETA: 18:39 - loss: 10.3376 - acc: 0.351 - ETA: 18:52 - loss: 10.2878 - acc: 0.354 - ETA: 18:55 - loss: 10.3490 - acc: 0.350 - ETA: 18:55 - loss: 10.2650 - acc: 0.356 - ETA: 18:54 - loss: 10.2897 - acc: 0.354 - ETA: 18:55 - loss: 10.1864 - acc: 0.361 - ETA: 18:55 - loss: 10.1799 - acc: 0.3615

```py
model_trained = final_model.fit([LSTM_train_X['left'], LSTM_train_X['right']], LSTM_train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                            validation_data=([LSTM_valid_X['left'], LSTM_valid_X['right']], LSTM_valid_y), verbose=1)
```

I have merged two models using keras.add()

```py
merged_output = add([branch1.output,branch2.output])
```

total code i have wrote::

```py
branch1 = Sequential()

branch1.add(Embedding(len(embeddings), embedding_dim, weights=[embeddings], input_length=max_seq_length, trainable=False))
branch1.add(LSTM(hidden_layer_nodes))


branch2 = Sequential()
branch2.add(Embedding(len(embeddings), embedding_dim, weights=[embeddings], input_length=max_seq_length, trainable=False))

branch2.add(LSTM(hidden_layer_nodes))


merged_output = add([branch1.output,branch2.output]) 


model_combined = Sequential()

model_combined.add(Activation('relu'))

model_combined.add(Dense(256))

model_combined.add(Activation('relu'))

model_combined.add(Dense(1))

model_combined.add(Activation('softmax'))

final_model = Model([branch1.input, branch2.input], model_combined(merged_output))


final_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='binary_crossentropy' , metrics=['accuracy'])

model_trained = final_model.fit([LSTM_train_X['left'], LSTM_train_X['right']], LSTM_train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                            validation_data=([LSTM_valid_X['left'], LSTM_valid_X['right']], LSTM_valid_y), verbose=1)
```

how to clear that issue?

Thanks:)

Comment: increase batch size to size of training data =D. Which version of keras do you use?

Comment: What is the actual issue? Its not clear from the question.

Comment: i am using keras 2.2.4